# Combobox text property twoway binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox as below

```
<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center"  
          Width="83.84"
          Canvas.Left="626.24"
          Canvas.Top="249.088" DataContext="{Binding Items[0]}"
          Text="{Binding TextVariable, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
          Height="68.293" 
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxDialogControlQ69_74}" />
```

**The problem is:** when I set the value for `TextVariable` in my view model it gets displayed on UI. But when I change it on UI it is not updated in the property.

I think I am missing something very obvious, any help is appreciated.

Comment: try to add UpdateSourceTriger="PropertyChanged" on your Binding and implement INotifyProperyChanged if you are not using this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works really good when i tried doing like below for Text binding on ComboBox,

```
Text="{Binding TextVariable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, NotifyOnValidationError=True, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
```

I have added one more property to make it editable.

```
IsEditable="True"
```

if you need the change on PropertyChange change UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

VM

```
 public string TextVariable {
        get 
        { return _TextVariable; }
        set 
        {
            _TextVariable = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged(); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: IsEditable="True" that was the thing I was missing. A friend pointed it out. Anyways Thanks Abin.